# Swapping information between ActionScript and Lingo

Tags: actionscript, lingo

I have a lingo script which runs some data processing for a Flash movie. I can call my Lingo functions from Flash by putting the following inside one of my methods:

```
getURL("Lingo: myMethod");
```

and I can pass parameters from flash to lingo as follows:

```
getURL("Lingo: myMethod param");
```

However, if myMethod returns a value, I can't seem to send it back to ActionScript. How do I code the following:

```
var myVar = getURL("Lingo: myMethod");
```

where myMethod is defined as:

```
on myMethod
    --do something
    return 5
end myMethod
```

We are using Flash 9 with CS 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access Lingo via `ExternalInterface` assuming you're in Flash 8 or greater:

```
import flash.system.ExternalInterface;
var valueFromLingo = ExternalInterface.call("myMethod");
trace(valueFromLingo); // -> 5
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know

Comment: We get back an undefined when we try this. Should I be using ExternalInterface.call("Lingo: myMethod")?

Answer (score 0):

@wulong:
the package is flash.external.*, not flash.system.*